# how to create A sequence of M natural numbers from 1 to N without duplication?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sequence

Write a function that returns all the ***Barcode*** that can be created in an array when M must be an even sequence of natural numbers from 1 to N and the length must be M.*

**condition**

- The sequence must be printed in increasing order in dictionary order.
- ***Barcode*** must be returned as a number.

```
function test (N, M) {
  
  
};
```

outputs should go like below

const output1 = test(2, 1);
console.log(output1); // --> [1, 2]

const output2 = test(3, 2);
console.log(output2); // --> [12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32]

const output3 = test(3, 3);
console.log(output3); // --> [123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]

I've tried solve this for hours , but I still can't get it. ... It's hard to even start.
I would appreciate it if you could help me solve the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
const test = (n, m) => {
  
  if(m > n){
   return []
  }

  const numbers = Array(n).fill(1).map((n, i) => (n + i).toString())

  const loop = (arr, res, elements) => {
    if (elements === 0) {
      return res.join('')
    }


    return arr.flatMap((a, i) => loop(arr.filter(b => b !== a), [...res, a], elements - 1))


  }
  return loop(numbers, [], m)
}

console.log(test(1, 1))
console.log(test(2, 1))
console.log(test(3, 2))
console.log(test(5, 3))
```

**Explanation**

first there is a check to ensure that `m` is lesser than `n` because in that case there are no possible combination

Internally this function uses a recursive function `loop` to calculate all possible combination of length **m**

the arguments are

- **arr** an array of elements
- **res** an accumulator of previous selected element
- **elements** the number of elements missing

at first the loop function is called with `numbers` as array , empty array as `res` and `m` as number of elements

First it checks if `elements` is zero (exit condition)

Then there it take the arr and do a `flatMap` over it

Foreach element it call the `loop` function recursively with argument

- **arr** previous array without current element
- **res** previous res + this element
- **elements** - 1

example (2, 2)

first run
loop(['1', '2'], [], 2)

elements > 0

loop(['2'], ['1'], 1)

- loop([], ['1', '2'], 0) -> return ['1', '2'].join('') = '12'

loop(['1'], ['2'], 1)

- loop([], ['2', '1'], 0) -> return ['2', '1'].join('') = '21'

Comment: good answer, but I think it needs a little bit of explanations.

Comment: @toffler you are right but I'm working now. I'll try to explain it later

Comment: @hound_woo I tried to add a rapid explanation